# Vb.NET How to populate listview columns like a tabulation of answers with data coming from database

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a listview activity, specifically a tabulation of evaluation answers.
I wanted to make it in listview that should look like this:

Ques. No | Question | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3

```
1    |  Ques. 1 |    4     |    3     |    1
2    |  Ques. 2 |    3     |    3     |    3
```

If I make a simple query of data like selecting question no, question, and answer from database (MySQL), I can populate the first three columns, but the problem is it only shows Answer 1 (or evaluator no. 1's set of answers). Is it possible to populate 4th and 5th columns (and so on if there are more evaluators) with different set of answers that are aligned to their respective question_id like this way (I mean like the sample table shown above)? How do I do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a sql query that produces the result you want? If you do, putting it in a list view should be trivial, if you don't then without knowing much more about the structure of your data there's little that can be said other than "looks like a job for pivot".